# SQL Server 2008 best way to distribute data simultaneously

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

We have a central DB and two temp DBs for other purposes. We want to send only some data when certain columns are updated to both DBs. Initially we've done two after update triggers but data entry fails when triggers enabled. Thus we was wondering what would be the best way to get required data and send to destination DBs.

Comment: whats the message when trigger fails?

Comment: More code, please.  Can you give some sample data and your triggers?

Comment: error updating doc error. The server principal "dbuser" is not able to access the database. 
"DestDb" under the current security context. We've resolved this error but still no data is being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers suck - do not get me wrong, I like them. BUt your Problem is that you are creating hard links between more and more machines. ONE Fails and (a) the Trigger throws an error and (b) one of the db's is out of sync. This gets complex when patching.

What you Need to do - is to get rid of the simultaneous requirement and use Queues, so you have the datbases decoupled. Replication also works. But you really hurt your uptime when you do that simultanously.

Comment: can you please how to use Queues please?

Comment: Start with the manual. This is a another question. SQL Server supports queues out of the box, and you should start really with the manual, then ask in a separate question about specifics you do not understand.